# Rails select helper. How do I select the default value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

In Rails erb, am using the snippet to show visiting team in a tournament match. How do I get to initially show the current visiting_team? What am I doing wrong?

```
<%= f.select(:visiting_team_id, Team.all.collect{|t| [t.name, t.id] }) %>
```

Comment: Note that in my case, only TournamentMatch has_one visiting_team. Its a one way association.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix is to explicitly specify the selected option. It now looks likes this and works

```
<%= f.select(:visiting_team_id, Team.all.collect{|t| [t.name, t.id]}, {:selected => @match.visiting_team_id.to_i}) %>
```

Comment: or is there a better alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

Just ensure that the object you're passing to `form_for` has the correct `visiting_team_id` set. Then, so long as there's a team that gets pulled out with that ID, it should work

Comment: It is correct; I checked by adding a <%= h @match.visiting_team_id%> and it shows the correct id.